# PowerShell: Compare DateTime by Month?

Tags: datetime, compare, powershell-2.0

What is the correct way to compare DateTime's by the month in PowerShell 2.0? In the end, I want to know if the current month is July or later, between July and December. The year doesn't matter. I'm not sure if there is a switch for month specific comparisons or try to get just the month and >= 7. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the PowerShell cmdlet called Get-Date.

```
If ((Get-Date).Month -ge 7){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this can help you:

```
C:\ps> [datetime]::Today.Month -gt ([datetime]"12/01/2012").month
False

C:\ps> [datetime]::Today.Month -gt ([datetime]"07/12/2012").month
True
```

The comparing date can be whatever you want, just the month is use for comparison.

This do the same:

```
C:\ps> [datetime]::Today.Month -gt 7
    False


C:\ps> [datetime]::Today.Month -gt 7
True
```